# Accessing dict_keys element by index in Python3

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.x, key

I'm trying to access a dict_key's element by its index:

```
test = {'foo': 'bar', 'hello': 'world'}
keys = test.keys()  # dict_keys object

keys.index(0)
AttributeError: 'dict_keys' object has no attribute 'index'
```

I want to get `foo`.

same with:

```
keys[0]
TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing
```

How can I do this?

Comment: as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72511703/19123103), `itertools.islice` provides a very fast way to index keys.

Answer (score 295, accepted):

Call `list()` on the dictionary instead:

```
keys = list(test)
```

In Python 3, the `dict.keys()` method returns a [dictionary view object](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects), which acts as a set. Iterating over the dictionary directly also yields keys, so turning a dictionary into a list results in a list of all the keys:

```
>>> test = {'foo': 'bar', 'hello': 'world'}
>>> list(test)
['foo', 'hello']
>>> list(test)[0]
'foo'
```

Answer (score 86):

Not a full answer but perhaps a useful hint. If it is really the first item you want*, then

```
next(iter(q))
```

is much faster than

```
list(q)[0]
```

for large dicts, since the whole thing doesn't have to be stored in memory.

For 10.000.000 items I found it to be almost 40.000 times faster.

*The first item in case of a dict being just a pseudo-random item before [Python 3.6](https://www.google.nl/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=python%20dict%20order%203.5&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=PGlvWNTrIa3c8AeKjpKACw) (after that it's ordered in the standard implementation, although it's not advised to rely on it).

Answer (score 16):

#### Python 3

```
mydict = {'a': 'one', 'b': 'two', 'c': 'three'}
mykeys = [*mydict]          #list of keys
myvals = [*mydict.values()] #list of values

print(mykeys)
print(myvals)
```

**Output**

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
['one', 'two', 'three']
```

Also see this [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16228248/how-can-i-get-list-of-values-from-dict)

Answer (score 9):

I wanted "key" & "value" pair of a first dictionary item. I used the following code.

```
 key, val = next(iter(my_dict.items()))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need to slice dictionary keys (not just the first key), instead of calling `list()` on `test`, generalize the method in [Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27638751/19123103) using `islice` from the built-in `itertools` module.

```py
from itertools import islice
# slice test.keys from index l to index u
some_keys = list(islice(test, l, u))
```

Depending on the size of the slice relative to the size of the dictionary, this method is 50% to >40000x faster than

```py
list(test)[l:u]
```

---

For example, in the example below, it's >43000x faster.

```py
n = 10_000_000
test = dict(zip(range(n), [0,1,2,3,4]*(n//5)))

%timeit list(islice(test, 10, 30))
# 4.43 µs ± 193 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit list(test)[10:30]
# 192 ms ± 2.65 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
test = {'foo': 'bar', 'hello': 'world'}
ls = []
for key in test.keys():
    ls.append(key)
print(ls[0])
```

Conventional way of appending the keys to a statically defined list and then indexing it for same

Answer (score 0):

In many cases, this may be an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  Why are you indexing your dictionary keys by position?  Do you really need to?  Until recently, dictionaries were not even ordered in Python, so accessing the first element was arbitrary.

I just translated some Python 2 code to Python 3:

```
keys = d.keys()
for (i, res) in enumerate(some_list):
    k = keys[i]
    # ...
```

which is not pretty, but not very bad either.  At first, I was about to replace it by the monstrous

```
    k = next(itertools.islice(iter(keys), i, None))
```

before I realised this is all much better written as

```
for (k, res) in zip(d.keys(), some_list):
```

which works just fine.

I believe that in many other cases, indexing dictionary keys by position can be avoided.  Although dictionaries are ordered in Python 3.7, relying on that is not pretty.  The code above only works because the contents of `some_list` had been recently produced from the contents of `d`.

Have a hard look at your code if you really need to access a `disk_keys` element by index.  Perhaps you don't need to.