# Python Pandas GroupBy get list of groups

Tags: python, pandas

I have a line of code:

```
g = x.groupby('Color')
```

The colors are Red, Blue, Green, Yellow, Purple, Orange, and Black. How do I return this list? For similar attributes, I use x.Attribute and it works fine, but x.Color doesn't behave the same way.

Comment: So you want a list of unique values in Color?

Comment: You can get the unique values from your orig df, no need to group `x['Color'].unique()`

Comment: The x['Color'].unique ended up being exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

There is much easier way of doing it:

```
g = x.groupby('Color')

g.groups.keys()
```

By doing `groupby()` pandas returns you a dict of grouped DFs.
You can easily get the key list of this dict by python built in function `keys()`.

Comment: This is much more `pandorable` than other answers. :)

Comment: Please look at Erik Swan's answer below before you make a decision on which method to use. If consistent ordering of group names is an issue, go for Erik's way.

Comment: `groupby()` does not return a `dict`, but a `DataFrameGroupBy` object.

Comment: In Python3.x the above code will throw a TypeError and `list(g.groups)` would be preferred, see also [the accepted answer in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552001/accessing-dict-keys-element-by-index-in-python3)

Comment: @Adriaan I get no errors when running this on Python 3.10.1, maybe an update changed that?

Comment: Perhaps, as I udnerstood from the comments in the question+answer I referred to it does not throw an error all the time. The list()-based solution is still preferred.

Answer (score 40):

If you do not care about the order of the groups, Yanqi Ma's answer will work fine:

```py
g = x.groupby('Color')
g.groups.keys()
list(g.groups) # or this
```

However, note that `g.groups` is a dictionary, so in Python <3.7 **the keys are inherently unordered!** This is the case even if you use `sort=True` on the `groupby` method to sort the groups, which is true by default.

This actually bit me hard when it resulted in a different order on two platforms, especially since I was using `list(g.groups)`, so it wasn't obvious at first that `g.groups` was a `dict`.

In my opinion, the best way to do this is to take advantage of the fact that the [GroupBy object has an iterator](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.__iter__.html), and use a list comprehension to return the groups in the order they exist in the GroupBy object:

```py
g = x.groupby('Color')
groups = [name for name,unused_df in g]
```

It's a little less readable, but this will always return the groups in the correct order.

Comment: just wondering how could I know attributes of GroupBy object? because as a premise, i think name should be one of attributes. However, I could not find relevant information in pandas document.

Comment: All of the methods and attributes of the GroupBy object are documented in [the Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/groupby.html).

Comment: The above concerns hold for Python versions prior to 3.7. For newer Python versions, dictionary keys _are_ [(insertion) ordered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323). I expect that `list(g.groups)==[name for name,_ in g]` is True, regardless of whether `sort=True` or `sort=False`.

Comment: Although the Pandas documentation doesn't explicitly state that, I agree that is probably true. Good to know this type of mistake is harder to make in Python 3.7+.

Answer (score 7):

Here's how to do it.

```
groups = list()
for g, data in x.groupby('Color'):
    print(g, data)
    groups.append(g)
```

The core idea here is this: if you iterate over a dataframe groupby iterator, you'll get back a two-tuple of (group name, filtered data frame), where filtered data frame contains  only records corresponding to that group).

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to get the unique values present in each column, you can do `numpy.unique(x[col_name].values)`

Answer (score 6):

It is my understanding that you have a Data Frame which contains multiples columns. One of the columns is "Color" which has different types of colors. You want to return a list of unique colors that exist.

```
colorGroups = df.groupby(['Color'])
for c in colorGroups.groups: 
    print c
```

The above code will give you all the colors that exist without repeating the colors names. Thus, you should get an output such as:

```
Red
Blue
Green
Yellow
Purple
Orange
Black
```

An alternative is the [unique()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html) function which returns an array of all unique values in a Series. Thus to get an array of all unique colors, you would do:

```
df['Color'].unique()
```

The output is an array, so for example `print df['Color'].unique()[3]` would give you `Yellow`.

Answer (score 5):

I compared runtime for the solutions above (with my data):

```
In [443]: d = df3.groupby("IND")

In [444]: %timeit groups = [name for name,unused_df in d]
377 ms ± 27.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [445]: % timeit  list(d.groups)
1.08 µs ± 47.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [446]: % timeit d.groups.keys()
708 ns ± 7.18 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [447]: % timeit df3['IND'].unique()
5.33 ms ± 128 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

it seems that the 'd.groups.keys()' is the best method.

Comment: Please post the entire used command and your results, if you want to write an answer that is actually contributing. Otherwise use the `comment` option.

Comment: It's not that simple, runtime will depend on the structure of your data. In my case - a df with few groups but many members per group - I found the exact opposite result: the list comprehension was fastest (22 ms), while `df.groupby(..).groups.keys()` was slower: 124ms.

Comment: Note: in my experiment, the first time I run `d.groups.keys()`, it is much slower (again 100-300 ms), but the second time it is 4ms. So your results may only depend on the order you do the timing in.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.. Happy Coding :)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['red','1','1.5'],['blue','20','2.5'],['red','15','4']],columns=(['color','column1','column2']))

list_req = list(df.groupby('color').groups.keys())
print(list_req)
```

[image]