# How to pick one key from a dictionary randomly

Tags: python, dictionary, random

I am a beginner of Python. I try to use this method:

```
random.choice(my_dict.keys())
```

but there is an error:

```
'dict_keys' object does not support indexing
```

my dictionary is very simple, like

```
my_dict = {('cloudy', 1 ): 10, ('windy', 1): 20}
```

Do you how to solve this problem? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 66, accepted):

To choose a random key from a dictionary named `my_dict`, you can use:

```
random.choice(list(my_dict))
```

This will work in both Python 2 and Python 3.

For more information on this approach, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18552025

Answer (score 0):

like this,

```
import random
def get_random_key(d: typing.Dict):
    target_pos = random.randint(1, min(1000, len(d) - 1))
    for i, key in enumerate(d):
        if i == target_pos:
            return key
```