# Unexpected output when printing dictionary keys

Tags: python

I'm using Spyder 4.1.2 in window 10, I ran the lines of code below:

```py
dict = {"Name": "Zara", "Age": 7}

print("Value: %s" % dict.keys())
```

I expected the output as a list:

```
['Name', 'Age']
```

But the output is

```
dict_keys(['Name', 'Age'])
```

Can anyone please tell me why? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to change your code to

```
dict = {"Name": "Zara", "Age": 7}
print("Value: %s" % list(dict.keys()))
```

Answer (score 2):

> Can anyone please tell me why?

In Python 3 `dict.keys()` is returning a `dict_keys` object which is actually a view object of that dict, and not a `list` object. That is why you don't see it printed as a regular list.

From the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects):

> The objects returned by `dict.keys()`, `dict.values()` and `dict.items()` are view objects. They provide a dynamic view on the dictionary’s entries, which means that when the dictionary changes, the view reflects these changes.
>   Dictionary views can be iterated over to yield their respective data, and support membership tests [...]

---

> How do I fix it?

You can directly cast the `dict` into a `list`, as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552001/accessing-dict-keys-element-by-index-in-python3):

```
my_dict = {"Name": "Zara", "Age": 7}
print("Value: %s" % list(my_dict))
```

Note that I replaced `dict` name with `my_dict`. It is highly recommended to avoid shadowing names, specifically built in names as `dict`.

Comment: @BillLe Does this answer your question?