# python3x TypeError: 'dict_keys'

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

This line of code generates dict_keys error:

```
Line:657    lr = LEARNING_RATE[LEARNING_RATE.keys()[0]]
```

error log:

```
  File "/home/dan/AcousticEventDetection-master/AED_train.py", line 657, in <module>
    lr = LEARNING_RATE[LEARNING_RATE.keys()[0]]
TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing
```

How to fix this error, please?

original code from:
https://github.com/kahst/AcousticEventDetection/blob/692535d6a282d0a356770c262f67347cdb56ece7/AED_train.py

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552001/accessing-dict-keys-element-by-index-in-python3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `keys()` will give you a view, not a `list`. Views are like `set`, they are unordered, so you can't index them. Check the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects).

Comment: kindly, if I want to re-write the above line, how it should be?

Comment: `lr = LEARNING_RATE[list(LEARNING_RATE)[0]]`, check also [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) for complete undesrtanding