# Python: select dictionary items by key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, key

I have this dictionary:

```
a = { 
    'car1': ('high cp', 'low fd', 'safe'),
    'car2': ('med cp', 'med fd', 'safe'), 
    'car3': ('low cp', 'high fd', 'safe'), 
    'taxi1': ('high cp', 'low fd', 'safe', 'med wt'), 
    'taxi2': ('high cp', 'low fd', 'safe', 'high wt'), 
    'taxi3': ('high cp', 'low fd', 'safe', 'high wt')
}
```

From the above dictionary, I want to create a new dictionary that consists only 'car%s'

I'm using this [code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545331/how-can-i-get-dictionary-key-as-variable-directly-in-python-not-by-searching-fr) (from another question)

```
b = {}
for key in a:
    if key == 'car%s'% (range (4)):
        print (" %s : %s" % (key, a[key]))
print(b)
```

It returns {}

I expect to get:

```
a = { 
    'car1': ('high cp', 'low fd', 'safe'),
    'car2': ('med cp', 'med fd', 'safe'), 
    'car3': ('low cp', 'high fd', 'safe'), 
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You are just printing keys with `car` in them, not adding them to another dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add keys which contain word `car` in it, then it will work:

```
a = { 
    'car1': ('high cp', 'low fd', 'safe'),
    'car2': ('med cp', 'med fd', 'safe'), 
    'car3': ('low cp', 'high fd', 'safe'), 
    'taxi1': ('high cp', 'low fd', 'safe', 'med wt'), 
    'taxi2': ('high cp', 'low fd', 'safe', 'high wt'), 
    'taxi3': ('high cp', 'low fd', 'safe', 'high wt')
}

b = {}
for key in a:
    if 'car' in key:
        print (key, a[key])
        b[key] = a[key]
print(b)
```

Comment: you beat me by 17 seconds :)

Answer (score 6):

You're checking the prefix the wrong way and you're not storing the result. You could use [`str.startswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) and dict comprehension to generate the result:

```
>>> a = { 
... 'car1': ('high cp', 'low fd', 'safe'),
... 'car2': ('med cp', 'med fd', 'safe'), 
... 'car3': ('low cp', 'high fd', 'safe'), 
... 'taxi1': ('high cp', 'low fd', 'safe', 'med wt'), 
... 'taxi2': ('high cp', 'low fd', 'safe', 'high wt'), 
... 'taxi3': ('high cp', 'low fd', 'safe', 'high wt')
... }
>>> res = {k: v for k, v in a.items() if k.startswith('car')}
>>> res
{'car2': ('med cp', 'med fd', 'safe'), 'car3': ('low cp', 'high fd', 'safe'), 'car1': ('high cp', 'low fd', 'safe')}
```

Instead of inserting a number to the format string your current check inserts the `range` object there which probably isn't the result you expect:

```
>>> 'car%s'% (range (4))
'carrange(0, 4)'
```

Answer (score 1):

You never do anything with the keys you validate but `print` them. You need to add them to your new dictionary:

```
b ={}
for key, val in a.items(): # .iteritems() for Python 2.x users
   if key == 'car%s' % (range (4)):
       b[key] = val
print(b)
```

Your code is would still be broken however. You need to make some changes:

- The only prefix you need to check is `"car"`. Forget trying to match the whole string.
- This entire for loop could be made into a very simple dictionary comprehension:

  ```
  >>> a = { 
  ... 'car1': ('high cp', 'low fd', 'safe'),
  ... 'car2': ('med cp', 'med fd', 'safe'), 
  ... 'car3': ('low cp', 'high fd', 'safe'), 
  ... 'taxi1': ('high cp', 'low fd', 'safe', 'med wt'), 
  ... 'taxi2': ('high cp', 'low fd', 'safe', 'high wt'), 
  ... 'taxi3': ('high cp', 'low fd', 'safe', 'high wt')
  ... }
  >>> {k: v for k, v in a.items() if k[0:3] == 'car'}
  {'car2': ('med cp', 'med fd', 'safe'), 
   'car3': ('low cp', 'high fd', 'safe'), 
   'car1': ('high cp', 'low fd', 'safe')}
  >>>
  ```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
new_dict = {}

for k in a.keys():
    if 'car' in k:
        new_dict[k] = a[k]
```

result:

```
>>new_dict
{'car1': ('high cp', 'low fd', 'safe'),
 'car2': ('med cp', 'med fd', 'safe'),
 'car3': ('low cp', 'high fd', 'safe')}
```

Answer (score 0):

what do you expect from range(4)?
It returns `[0, 1, 2, 3]`

```
b = {}
for key in range(4):
    new_key = "car%s" % key # generate new_key
    item = a.get(new_key)
    if item is not None:
        b[new_key] = item
print (b)
```

OR you want to get items only starts with `car`,
read this link
https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith

```
b = {}
for key, value in a.items():
    if key.startswith("car"):
        b[key] = a[key]
print (b)
```

output

```
{'car2': ('med cp', 'med fd', 'safe'), 
'car3': ('low cp', 'high fd', 'safe'), 
'car1': ('high cp', 'low fd', 'safe')}
```